# How to return a copy of an instance of a class?

Tags: python

I am currently practising `python` on code wars, here is a prompt:

Create a `Vector` object that supports addition, subtraction, dot products, and norms. So, for example:

```
    a = Vector([1, 2, 3])
    b = Vector([3, 4, 5])
    c = Vector([5, 6, 7, 8])

    a.add(b)      # should return a new Vector([4, 6, 8])
    a.subtract(b) # should return a new Vector([-2, -2, -2])
    a.dot(b)      # should return 1*3 + 2*4 + 3*5 = 26
    a.norm()      # should return sqrt(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2) = sqrt(14)
    a.add(c)      # raises an exception
```

I have written functions add and subtract that pass some of the tests. However, I am running into issues with overwriting my previous list values of 'a' after running the add function. When I go into subtract, the 'a' values in the `vector` are the summations computed from the previous instance of the add function.

I suspect its due to me running this line of code:
`return self.__class__(self.list)` causing the instance of the class to overwrite itself.

Kindly please help, I believe I need to return a copy of the instance of the class but don't know how to do it.

```
    class Vector:

      def __init__(self, list):

          self.list = list #[1,2]
          self.copylist = list

      def add(self,Vector):

          try:
              self.list = self.copylist

              #take list from other vector
              other = Vector.list

              #take each value from other Vector and add it to self.list
              for index,item in enumerate(Vector.list,0):
                  self.list[index] = item + self.list[index]


          except:
              print("Different size vectors")
          #return the instance of a class
          return self.__class__(self.list)

       def subtract(self,Vector):

          self.list = self.copylist
          other = Vector.list

          print(self.list)
          print(other)

          for index,item in enumerate(Vector.list,0):
              self.list[index] = self.list[index] - item

          return self.__class__(self.list)

       def dot(self,Vector):
          self.list = self.copylist
          other = Vector.list

          #print(self.list)
          #print(other)

          running_sum =0

          for index,item in enumerate(Vector.list,0):
              running_sum = running_sum + item * self.list[index]
              #print(running_sum, " ", self.list[index], " ", item)

          return running_sum

       def norm(self):
          running_sum = 0

          for item in self.list:
              running_sum += item**2

          return running_sum ** 0.5

       def toString(self):
          return str(self.list)

      `def equals(self,Vector):
          return self.list == Vector.list
```

Here are some of the tests:

```
    a = Vector([1, 2])
    b = Vector([3, 4])

    test.expect(a.add(b).equals(Vector([4, 6])))


    a = Vector([1, 2, 3])
    b = Vector([3, 4, 5])

    test.expect(a.add(b).equals(Vector([4, 6, 8])))
    test.expect(a.subtract(b).equals(Vector([-2, -2, -2]))) #code fails here
    test.assert_equals(a.dot(b), 26)
    test.assert_equals(a.norm(), 14 ** 0.5)
```

Comment: where does this `test` variable comes from?

Comment: Does my answer make sense to you and give you what you want?  I got some upvotes, but I don't know if they came from you as you didn't accept my answer as addressing your question by clicking the checkmark to note this.  I hope this answered your question sufficiently.  If you have any specific questions, about my answer, I'd be happy to help you to understand what's going on.  The bottom line is that my code is just doing basic Python object manipulation and creation, and not trying to do anything with references to the Vector class itself.  Needing to do that sort of stuff is unusual.

Comment: I apologize Steve, your code helped. I have selected the check mark option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You shouldn't be working with class objects at all.  You should just be working with instances of the Vector class. Here's what I think your code should look like:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, initial_elements):

        self.elements = list(initial_elements) # make a copy of the incoming list of elements

    def add(self, other):

        # insure that the two vectors match in length
        if len(self.elements) != len(other.elements):
            raise Exception("Vector sizes are different")

        # copy our elements
        r = list(self.elements)

        # add the elements from the second vector
        for index, item in enumerate(other.elements, 0):
            r[index] += item

        # return a new vector object defined by the computed elements
        return Vector(r)

    def subtract(self, other):

        # insure that the two vectors match in length
        if len(self.elements) != len(other.elements):
            raise Exception("Vector sizes are different")

        # copy our elements
        r = list(self.elements)

        # subtract the elements from the second vector
        for index, item in enumerate(other.elements, 0):
            r[index] -= item

        # return a new vector object defined by the computed elements
        return Vector(r)

    def dot(self, other):

        running_sum = 0

        for index, item in enumerate(other.elements, 0):
            running_sum += item * self.elements[index]

        return running_sum

    def norm(self):
        running_sum = 0

        for item in self.elements:
            running_sum += item ** 2

        return running_sum ** 0.5

    def toString(self):
        return str(self.elements)

    def equals(self, other):
        return self.elements == other.elements

def test():
    a = Vector([1, 2])
    b = Vector([3, 4])
    print(a.add(b).equals(Vector([4, 6])))

    a = Vector([1, 2, 3])
    b = Vector([3, 4, 5])

    print(a.add(b).equals(Vector([4, 6, 8])))
    print(a.subtract(b).equals(Vector([-2, -2, -2])))
    print(a.dot(b) == 26)
    print(a.norm() == 14 ** 0.5)

test()
```

Result:

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

The general structure of your code is spot on.

One thing to note is that you shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name, as it is a type name in Python.  Also, you don't want to be passing around `Vector` as a value.  You want to be passing instances of `Vector` and `list`, with names that do not conflict with these type names.

My solution assumes you want Vector instances to be immutable, so each of your operations will return a new Vector object.  You could also have them not be immutable and have, for example, the `add` method just add the incoming vector into the target vector without creating a new object.  I like keeping them immutable.  I've been doing more and more of this "functional style" programming lately, where calls to object methods don't modify the target object (don't have side effects), but rather just return a new object.

I like your use of the `test` class to do your testing.  I chose to not deal with this, and just print the results of each test comparison to see that they all come out to `True`.  I'll leave it to you to restore your tests to using a test object with `expect` and `assert_equals` methods.

UPDATE: Here is a more compact way to write your `add` and `subtract` methods:

```
def add(self, other):

    # insure that the two vectors match in length
    if len(self.elements) != len(other.elements):
        raise Exception("Vector sizes are different")

    return Vector([self.elements[i] + other.elements[i] for i in range(len(self.elements))])

def subtract(self, other):

    # insure that the two vectors match in length
    if len(self.elements) != len(other.elements):
        raise Exception("Vector sizes are different")

    return Vector([self.elements[i] - other.elements[i] for i in range(len(self.elements))])
```

Comment: I appreciate the support, Thank you Steve, I figured out the issue I was having was due to variable names being mixed up. I had the Vector variable name passed into the functions of add and subtract. This resulted me in having a error "Vector object is not callable". Lastly, just out of curiosity why did you convert the copied incoming list in the add and subtract method?   **# copy our element r = list(self.elements)** , when the list is passed into the **__init__()** method you convert the incoming list to a list already?

Comment: I'm glad I could be so helpful.  That's great.  The reason I copy the target object's elements is that I don't want to modify the target object itself.  If changes are applied to the object's own copy of that list, then the object itself is changed.  Copying the list says "we're going to construct a new list from which we will build a new Vector object".  This is exactly where the question of "immutable" comes in.  If you didn't want to follow an immutable model, you wouldn't make this copy.  That's the one extra step that embodies the mutable/immutable decision.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
return self.__class__(self.list)
```

to:

```
return self
```

although this would the same as,

```
return Vector(self.list)
```

if the class is more complicated it is better to return self

I think that's the issue, hope it helps :)

also, it is good practice to use different names. you used Vector for the class name as well as many of the inputs of the functions, you will run into problems when you do that.

Comment: `return self` is not the same as `return Vector(self.list)`.  The former returns a reference to the target object whereas the second returns a new object that is a copy of the final state of the target object.  As returning a copy in this way assumes that the original object was modified, there's probably no reason to return a copy of the target object as the target object itself must at this point have been modified per the target operation.  You either want to `return self` or return `Vector(computed_list)`, where in the latter case, you want to not have modified the target object itself.

Comment: ...either approach should work fine.  The distinction is the question I pose at the end of my answer as to if you want the Vector object to be immutable or not.

Comment: @Steve  return Vector(self.list) is the same as return self cos in this case, the computation was done on self.list

Comment: @Steve I see why you want it to be immutable. I like that too cos I use numpy that way.

Comment: Kenivia, the two are still not the same.  You're creating a new object in one case and returning a reference to an existing object in the other.  Maybe what you're saying is that the result is the same, but that's only possibly true depending on what you go on to do with the returned reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please change function toString to **str** . its' already done.

```
class Vector : 
    def __init__(self , lst_vec):
        self.lst_vec = lst_vec

    def show_vector(self):
        return self.lst_vec

    def add(self , v ):
        size_self = len(self.lst_vec)
        size_v = len(v.lst_vec)
        new_vector = []
        if ( size_self != size_v ):
            return Exception("error add")
        else:
            for i in range(size_self):
                new_vector.append(self.lst_vec[i] + v.lst_vec[i])
        return Vector(new_vector)

    def subtract(self , v ): 
        size_self = len(self.lst_vec)
        size_v = len(v.lst_vec)
        new_vector = []
        if ( size_self != size_v ):
            return Exception("error subtract")
        else:
            for i in range(size_self):
                new_vector.append(self.lst_vec[i] - v.lst_vec[i])
        return Vector(new_vector)

    def dot(self , v ):
        size_self = len(self.lst_vec)
        size_v = len(v.lst_vec)
        new_vector = []
        sum_vec = 0 
        if ( size_self != size_v ):
            return Exception("Vector sizes are different")
        else:
            for i in range(size_self):
                new_vector.append(self.lst_vec[i] * v.lst_vec[i])
        for i in range(len(new_vector)):
            sum_vec+=new_vector[i]
        return sum_vec

    def norm (self):
        new_vec_sum = 0
        for i in range(len(self.lst_vec)):
            new_vec_sum +=( self.lst_vec[i] ) **2
        return new_vec_sum ** 0.5

    def toString(self):
        str_self = '('
        for i in range(len(self.lst_vec)):
            str_self += str(self.lst_vec[i])
            if i < (len(self.lst_vec)-1):
                str_self+=','
            else : pass 
        str_self+=')'
        return str_self

    def equals(self , v ):
        return self.lst_vec == v.lst_vec 

a = Vector([1,2,3])
b = Vector([3,4,5])
c = Vector([5,6,7,8])
print(a.add(b).show_vector())
print( a.add(b).equals(Vector([4,6,8])) )
print(a.subtract(b).show_vector())
print(a.dot(b))
print(a.norm())
print((a.toString() == '(1,2,3)'))
print(c.toString())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).